# javascript new message and scroll

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

im creating a chat app, when the new message comes, scroll is not coming to the bottom.

```js
var messageBody = document.querySelector('.msg');
messageBody.scrollTop = (messageBody.scrollHeight - messageBody.clientHeight);
```

This is my code. It's working, but last message is not appear.

For example; the users send 500 message, scrollbar is staying 499. message. If new message is coming, so totally 501 message, scrollbar is staying 500. message. It's not showing last message. How to fix it, if you help me i will be glad.

Edit: My function is:

```js
  methods: {
    sendFunc() {
      if(this.msgInput != null && this.msgInput != '') {
        let ms = { name : 'emre', msg: this.msgInput, time: '12:02' }
        this.messages.push(ms);
        this.msgInput = '';
        var messageBody = document.querySelector('.msg');
        messageBody.scrollTop = (messageBody.scrollHeight + messageBody.clientHeight);
      }
    },
```

Comment: Maybe you put message after scrolling? Can u share more code?

Comment: Of course sir,  i edited my message

Comment: In addition, if i put this code to the mounted instance, the codes are working fine. Last message always appears. But in the send message function, its not working.

Comment: What do "messages"?if DOM is chanching after update messages array? Have You check in debuger if your message is adding?